# Why is my get_factors function giving me a "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that can return all the possible factors of a given number. I am using recursion and I don't know why am getting the error.

I know that the error occurs at the "for factor in factors" line towards the end.

```
def get_factors(number: int):

    factors = []

    if number % 2 == 0:  # Checks if number is divisible by all the primes up
        factors.append(2)  # to 19
        factors += get_factors(int(number/2))

    elif number % 3 == 0:
        factors.append(3)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/3))

    elif number % 5 == 0:
        factors.append(5)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/5))

    elif number % 7 == 0:
        factors.append(7)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/7))

    elif number % 11 == 0:
        factors.append(11)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/11))

    elif number % 13 == 0:
        factors.append(13)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/13))

    elif number % 17 == 0:
        factors.append(17)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/17))

    elif number % 19 == 0:
        factors.append(19)
        factors += get_factors(int(number/19))

    else:

        final = [1, number]

        for digit in range(1, int(number/2) + 1):  # Checks that there isn't
            if number % digit == 0:  # a factor prime that isn't listed above. 
                factors.append(digit)

        for factor in factors:
            final += [factor**power for power in range(1, factors.count(factor) + 1)]  # A way to ensure that repeated numbers are turned into factors.

        return sorted(final)
```

Comment: You only return in the else-clause; any of the if-elif clauses doesn't return, and thus automatically returns `None`. Which is the `None` mentioned in the error message: You'd get something like `factors += None` at a point.

Comment: Please fix your formatting by adding the first line to the code block: use the `{}` code block formatting option, for example.

Comment: You can also use integer division in Python with `number // 2`, instead of `int(number/2)`. That is probably clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be an acceptable solution to store the factors in a global variable (or you could wrap all this code in a function too...). I took out the return and changed all the `factors.append()` to `total_factors.append()` as well as changing `factors += get_factors()` to `get_factors()` (since it has no return value after I took it out).

Resulting code:

```
total_factors = []

def get_factors(number: int):
    factors = []

    if number % 2 == 0:  # Checks if number is divisible by all the primes up
        total_factors.append(2)  # to 19
        get_factors(int(number/2))

    elif number % 3 == 0:
        total_factors.append(3)
        get_factors(int(number/3))

    elif number % 5 == 0:
        total_factors.append(5)
        get_factors(int(number/5))

    elif number % 7 == 0:
        total_factors.append(7)
        get_factors(int(number/7))

    elif number % 11 == 0:
        total_factors.append(11)
        get_factors(int(number/11))

    elif number % 13 == 0:
        total_factors.append(13)
        get_factors(int(number/13))

    elif number % 17 == 0:
        total_factors.append(17)
        get_factors(int(number/17))

    elif number % 19 == 0:
        total_factors.append(19)
        get_factors(int(number/19))

    else:

        final = [1, number]

        for digit in range(1, int(number/2) + 1):  # Checks that there isn't
            if number % digit == 0:  # a factor prime that isn't listed above.
                factors.append(digit)

        for factor in factors:
            final += [factor**power for power in range(1, factors.count(factor) + 1)]  # A way to ensure that repeated numbers are turned into factors.

get_factors(300)
print(total_factors)
```

Output

> [2, 2, 3, 5, 5]

And 2*2*3*5*5 == 300 so this checks out!

It does seem there are additional difficulties in your `else` block though. When I try `getfactors(366)` it only outputs:

> [2, 3]

But this should get you headed in the right direction still :)